# nil check and error check in single if statement

Tags: if-statement, go

I was attempting to do a nil check and then a method error check in a single if statement. Since the OR operator won't check any other conditions if the first one is true, I figured I could do something like this, to avoid nil pointer crashes and handle errors together:

```golang
if (uc.registry == nil) || (serviceName, err = uc.registry.GetServiceName(itemKind, key); err != nil) {}
```

This gives a syntax error, as it seems to try comparing the result of the first condition with the string value of `serviceName`.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditions must appear on the right-hand side of the `;` if it is present, [per the documentation](https://golang.org/ref/spec#If_statements). It is a shorthand for simple cases like error checks and map lookups. What you're doing would require two `if` statements.